# Prove using the epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, epsilon-delta

> Prove using the epsilon-delta ($\epsilon-\delta$) definition of a limit that
> $$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^2-4}{-x^2+7x-10}=\frac{4}{3}.$$

I am perplexed about how to solve this question, tried all the ways, and wasted hours and hours. Any solving is highly appreciated

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried making the limit x-2<δ  and x2−4/−x2+7x−10 -(4/3) <ϵ

Comment: Hint: first simplify the fraction to $\frac{2+x}{5-x}$ for all $x\ne2$.

Comment: i simplified the fraction got -7(x-2)/3(x-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that, for $x\notin\{2,5\}$, we have that

$$\frac{x^2-4}{-x^2+7x-10}=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{-(x-2)(x-5)}=-\frac{x+2}{x-5}.$$

Furthermore

$$\left\lvert-\frac{x+2}{x-5}-\frac{4}{3}\right\rvert=\frac{7}{3}\left\lvert\frac{x-2}{x-5}\right\rvert.$$

Now if we restrict ourselves to that we have that $\lvert x-2\rvert<1$, then it is easy to check that we also have that $\lvert x-5\rvert>1$. Set

$$\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{3}{7}\varepsilon\right\}.$$

Then, if $\lvert x-2\rvert<\delta$, it follows that

$$\frac{7}{3}\left\lvert\frac{x-2}{x-5}\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Combining this with the first equalities, the result follows.

Comment: but how would that result in finding delta?

Comment: @AliAsad what do you mean? We choose $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{3}{7}\varepsilon\right\}$, so do you not see why that choice works?

Comment: I got through the question now. I understand very well. Thanks a lot, for the guidance